# Lifetime of static variable used as item counter

Tags: vba, excel, static

I have declared a static variable to use as an item counter. The spreadsheet is going to be updated by different people running the code and saving the workbook afterwards. However, when I test my code and make any changes to it, the static variable resets to `1`:

```
Static strn, mechn, ein As Integer
Dim i, lrow As Long
Dim num as String
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("test")

lrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

i = 1

If reqb = "blah" Then

    Do Until ws.Range("B" & i).Value = "bloop"
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    strn = strn + 1

    num = "1-" & strn

End If
```

Will it ever reset after I finalize my code?

Comment: it will be reset each time the wkb is closed. If you want to make some sort of counter, you can put the value in a cell and have  1 added to that cell value each time a user runs the sub and pick up your desired count that way. If you leave the workbook open, once your code is set it appears that the variable will not reset.

Comment: As for the variable's lifetime... You need to tell us where this code is located and how it's scoped.

Comment: @Mat'sMug The code is located inside a private subroutine that is called upon by a userform button. And thank you very much for the comment - i will make sure to clean up that bit - since I'm self taught i might have a lot of bad habits

Comment: To add to what @ScottHoltzman said - it will be reset whenever the workbook is opened *and* whenever the workbook's VBProject is reset (e.g. if an unhandled error occurs during code execution)

Comment: So the `static` variables live inside a class module then (form's code-behind)? Make your life simpler, promote that static variable to an instance-level field (i.e. module-level), and expose a `Public Property Get` member to retrieve the value from the outside. The variable will live and die with the form instance. Things get complicated quickly with forms, because they're classes *with a default instance* - a static variable's lifetime will vary depending on how you're using the form (i.e. are you creating a new instance, or using the default one?)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thank you very much - your answers have been extremely helpful. I will definitely look into Rubberduck (btw, the name kicks seroius ass)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments to your answer, your 'static' variable resets whenever the project / workbook is closed. To make a permanent variable, attach it to an excel object. As noted in the comments, the easiest way to do this is to assign the value to a cell; other options include creating an invisible shape and adjusting the title of that shape, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for a variable to survive the project / workbook being closed is to use the environment. The advantage here is that the variable will disappear when the Excel Application is closed.

The environment can be set via the "kernel32" function "SetEnvironmentVariableA" and read for example by using the "WScript.Shell" object. Please note that the function "Environ" will not reflect changes made via the Set function.

Example:

```
    Declare Function SetEnvVar Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetEnvironmentVariableA" _
    (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal lpValue As String) As Long

    Function GetEnvVar(VarName As String)
        Set Ex = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd /C echo %" & VarName & "%")
        GetEnvVar = Ex.StdOut.ReadLine
    End Function 'GetEnvVar

    Sub Main()
        SetEnvVar "MyVar", "My Info"
        MyVar = GetEnvVar("MyVar")      ''' MyVar = "My Info"
        NotMyVar = Environ("MyVar")     ''' NotMyVar = ""
    End Sub 'Main
```